# Access Web.config from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, appsettings

I was searching for the way to access the web.config data from the js file
I found a solution:

```
var uri = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"].ToString())';
```

But what I get is the '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"].ToString())' string. I would be grateful if someone could point me the error.

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in your view? The Razor engine parses views (.cshtml), not JavaScript files.

Comment: it is in js file
is there a way to somehow read this data and make it global for all the js files?

Comment: You could. Or you could embed a small script inline on your view and pass it to your script. Or just declare a global variable in an inline script on your layout page that exposes this basic configuration, that your JavaScript files would then access.

Comment: I'm sorry could you please show to use the second variant?

Comment: If `window` is available at the time you're running the script, you can use it, as it's global scope. Not best practice, but it works. `window.whatever = {//myObject}`. (This way you can use a single object for all your custom stuff. You can also put functions in it, of course... Access it with `window.whatever.property` or `window.whatever.property()`. And change `whatever` to something meaningful and unique.

Comment: Your 2 answers actually solved the issue for me)

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in a view, perhaps your Layout page if you want to make it available to all scripts.

```
<script>
window.RootUri = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"].ToString())';
</script>
```

Then any scripts in .js files can access it via `window.RootUri`.